# Scan directory for text files and insert text file data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, text, insert

I finally got CLOSE to what I want with the help of Sephedo and Varun. Here is the code....

What IS happening now is that I'm gettting mysql error wrong syntax because of 's in the txt file data. How and where would I make the sql query ignore the 's and any other char that might throw off mysql

```
<?php

//Open connection
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "testing";
    $password = "*******";
    $dbname = "zadmin_testing";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
/**
 * @author - Sephedo
 * @for - Randall @ Stackoverflow
 * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704981/read-each-line- of-text-of-each-file-in-a-directory-and-place-into-array/18705231#18705231
 */

$directory = 'data/'; // The directory to the lesson text files

$linesToReturn = 9; // Set to nine for the number of lines in each text file  ( for expansion? )

// Find all files in the directory which are .txt files
foreach( glob( $directory . "*.txt" ) as $filename )
{
    // Open the file
    if( $handle = @fopen( $filename, "r") )
    {
        $x = 0; // Start the line counter

        // Cycle each line until end or reach the lines to return limit
        while(! feof( $handle ) or $x < $linesToReturn )
        {
            $line = fgets($handle); // Read the line

            $lessons[$filename][] = $line;

            $x++; // Increase the counter
        }

        // This lines makes sure that are exactly x# of lines in each lesson
        if( count( $lessons[$filename] ) != $linesToReturn ) unset(   $lessons[$filename] );
    }
}

// creates a blank list if no files or valid files were found.
if(! isset( $lessons ) ) $lessons = array();
foreach( $lessons AS $file => $details )

//Creates your data into a query
        {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (date, title, type, cover, genre, vrating, path, mrating, description) VALUES ('$details[0]', '$details[1]', '$details[2]', '$details[3]', '$details[4]', '$details[5]', '$details[6]', '$details[7]', '$details[8]')";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully <br>";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);

        }
        }
//Close mysql connection
 mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

THE CODE I STARTED FROM

```
/**
 * @author - Sephedo
 * @for - Randall @ Stackoverflow
 * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704981/read-each-line- of-text-of-each-file-in-a-directory-and-place-into-array/18705231#18705231
 */

$directory = 'lessons/'; // The directory to the lesson text files

$linesToReturn = 4; // Set to four for the number of lines in each text file ( for expansion? )

// Find all files in the directory which are .txt files
foreach( glob( $directory . "*.txt" ) as $filename )
{
    // Open the file
    if( $handle = @fopen( $filename, "r") )
{
    $x = 0; // Start the line counter

    // Cycle each line until end or reach the lines to return limit
    while(! feof( $handle ) or $x < $linesToReturn )
    {
        $line = fgets($handle); // Read the line

        $lessons[$filename][] = $line;

        $x++; // Increase the counter
    }

    // This lines makes sure that are exactly 4 lines in each lesson
    if( count( $lessons[$filename] ) != $linesToReturn ) unset(       $lessons[$filename] );
    }
}

// creates a blank list if no files or valid files were found.
if(! isset( $lessons ) ) $lessons = array();

// The rest of the page just builds a simple table to display each lesson.-
echo '<h1>Lesson Plans</h1>';
echo '<table>';
echo '<th>Lesson Number</th><th>Lesson Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Due    Date</th>';

foreach( $lessons as $file => $details )
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $details[0] . '</td><td>' . $details[1] . '</td><td>' .    $details[2] . '</td><td>' . $details[3] . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Shouldnt your insert statement be inside the loop?

Comment: could you show me where you'd place it?

Comment: Yes. And your hint got me there! Thank you!!!

Comment: It's better to write the answer as a separate post and mark it as answer.

Comment: I spoke to soon. It does work, somewhat...